# Paragraph covers div brought through transition

Tags: html, css

Why does the paragraph always cover the div that is shown when you hover over link 1 in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/taylorrowser/Lwh6o9xx/)? I have tried changing the z-index of both the paragraph and the list, but nothing works. The thing that really makes me not understand is the fact that during the transition, the list appears over the paragraph. Then, after the transition, the paragraph seems to change z-index. Any help would be great.

```css
div {
  background-color: #BFBFBF;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.NavList {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.NavListItem {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
.NavListItem:Hover .NavLink {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  color: #BFBFBF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.NavLink {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  color: #BFBFBF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #404040;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.NavListItem:Hover .SubNavList {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity 5s;
}
.NavListItem:Hover .SubNavListItem {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.NavListItem:Hover .SubNavLink {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  color: #BFBFBF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.NavListItem:Hover .SubNavLink:Hover {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  color: #BFBFBF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #404040;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.SubNavList {
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 5s;
  z-index: 100;
}
.SubNavListItem {
  display: none;
}
p {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <ul class="NavList">
      <li class="NavListItem">
        <a href="#" class="NavLink">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="NavListItem">
        <a href="#" class="NavLink">Link 1</a>
        <ul class="SubNavList">
          <li class="SubNavListItem">
            <a href="#" class="SubNavLink">SubLink 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="SubNavListItem">
            <a href="#" class="SubNavLink">SubLink 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="NavListItem">
        <a href="#" class="NavLink">Link 2</a>
        <ul class="SubNavList">
          <li class="SubNavListItem">
            <a href="#" class="SubNavLink">SubLink 3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="SubNavListItem">
            <a href="#" class="SubNavLink">SubLink 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="NavListItem">
        <a href="#" class="NavLink">Link3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Try positioning it absolutely or fixed. That could work. Tell me what you find. Good luck!

Comment: A 5 second transition for a menu dropdown seems bananas.

Comment: It won't actually be 5 seconds,

Comment: I just slowed it down so I could make sure it was happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Z-index depends on the element having "positioning." Give your `div` and you `p` position like so:

```
div,p {
    position: relative;
}
```

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/9dp7p5LL/

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
p {     
    display: block;
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[See the updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwh6o9xx/4/)

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` applies to positioned elements.

[**source**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

In your example you don't need negative `z-index` to `p` elements. You can just apply `position: relative` with a high `z-index` to `.NavListItem:Hover .SubNavLink:hover` like:

```css
div {
  background-color: #BFBFBF;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.NavList {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.NavListItem {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
.NavListItem:Hover .NavLink {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  color: #BFBFBF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.NavLink {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  color: #BFBFBF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #404040;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.NavListItem:Hover .SubNavList {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity 5s;
}
.NavListItem:Hover .SubNavListItem {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.NavListItem:Hover .SubNavLink {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  color: #BFBFBF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.NavListItem:Hover .SubNavLink:Hover {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  color: #BFBFBF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #404040;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.SubNavList {
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 5s;
  z-index: 100;
}
.SubNavListItem {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <ul class="NavList">
      <li class="NavListItem">
        <a href="#" class="NavLink">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="NavListItem">
        <a href="#" class="NavLink">Link 1</a>
        <ul class="SubNavList">
          <li class="SubNavListItem">
            <a href="#" class="SubNavLink">SubLink 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="SubNavListItem">
            <a href="#" class="SubNavLink">SubLink 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="NavListItem">
        <a href="#" class="NavLink">Link 2</a>
        <ul class="SubNavList">
          <li class="SubNavListItem">
            <a href="#" class="SubNavLink">SubLink 3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="SubNavListItem">
            <a href="#" class="SubNavLink">SubLink 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="NavListItem">
        <a href="#" class="NavLink">Link3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</body>
```